# Firebase: getting a weird `e` object when performing a get

Tags: javascript, firebase

Not sure what this is supposed to be or why it's happening, but I am trying to do a simple `get` on a collection I have in Firebase, however am getting the following object:

```
e {_firestore: o, _key: e, _document: e, _fromCache: false, _hasPendingWrites: false}
exists: true
id: "tOswoypflMS1gBPpfWmEenldBPm2"
metadata: t
ref: n
_document: e {key: e, version: n, data: a, proto: {…}, hasLocalMutations: false, …}
_firestore: o {_queue: t, INTERNAL: {…}, _config: Gc, _databaseId: e, _dataConverter: t, …}
_fromCache: false
_hasPendingWrites: false
_key: e {path: e}
__proto__: Object
```

It turns out I can't even do a `JSON.stringify` on as it causes the following error:

> index.js:1375 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>
> --> starting at object with constructor 'e'
>
> |     property 'firebase_' -> object with constructor 'Object'
>
> |     property 'apps' -> object with constructor 'Array'
>
> --- index 0 closes the circle

Is there an issue with my schema or something that I am simply not understanding?
My call is as follows:

```
  import { db } from '../firebase'

  const clients =  await db
        .collection('clients')
        .doc('A_VALID_CLIENT_ID')
        .get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a `get()` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot), not a plain data object. You probably want to do any serialization on `.data()` from the snapshot instead.