# How to get data from an object visible on browser console but returns null when I manually traverse it on my code?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, twilio, console.log

```
//listen for messages
channel.on("messageAdded", function (message) {
    //render new message    
    console.log("New awesome message", message)
    //this is null for some reason
    console.log("Stringify 3",JSON.stringify(message.state.aggregatedDeliveryReceipt))
}
```

But by storing it as a global object via console right click,
[image: object]

I am able to do a
`console.log(temp1.state.aggregatedDeliveryReceipt)`

and get back

[image: Delivery receipt state]

The problem is that, when I use the same `state.aggregatedDeliveryReceipt`
on my JS file, I am unable to get the desired result. It says that it is `null`

After googling some, I learned it was some sort of constructor...

[Firebase: getting a weird `e` object when performing a get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013692/firebase-getting-a-weird-e-object-when-performing-a-get)

What I have tried:

1. used `JSON.stringify()` on temp1

Result:
*Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'l'
|     property '_fsm' -> object with constructor 'o'
--- property 'context' closes the circle*

2. used it on `temp1.state`

Result:

```
{"sid":"IMd0XXXXXXXfd8aa","index":532,"author":"XXXX","body":"XXXX","timestamp":"2020-XXXXX:12.XX","dateUpdated":"2020-11-XXXXX:12.574Z","lastUpdatedBy":null,"attributes":{},"type":"text","media":null,"participantSid":"MB0a5d2XXXXXXX27ddf4da6","aggregatedDeliveryReceipt":null}
```

3. used it on `temp1.state.aggregatedDeliveryReceipt` and is also returned `null`
4. Directly doing it on console
   [image: log]
   Result: it worked but I am unable to replicate it on my JS file. For some reason, the console can see it directly but not through my code

Comment: It is likely a timing issue if you are getting different behavior in the devtools console vs in your code. The data may well have loaded by the time you try to access it in the devtools console, whereas it likely hasn't if you are accessing it too soon in your code. As a first step, use `setTimeout()` to defer the code reading the value by a decent amount of time (a few seconds) and then see if it can be read correctly. Then at least you will know what the problem is.

Comment: Your assumptions were spot on! I While I can see it being logged(untouched), I am unable to traverse the delivery receipt... By delaying it for 3 seconds, I was able to get results from serialization. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't even need to ```stringify``` the deliveryReceipt, all I had to do was to delay the reading of that particular object property... Perhaps a Twilio websocket problem, or an error on my part. Anyway, it was solved(I am able to parse and see the value). Would you like to submit an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely a timing issue if you are getting different behavior in the devtools console vs in your code. The data may well have loaded by the time you try to access it in the devtools console, whereas it likely hasn't if you are accessing it too soon in your code.

As a first step, use `setTimeout()` to defer the code reading the value by a decent amount of time (a few seconds) and then see if it can be read correctly. Then at least you will know what the problem is.